# How to format text create by a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html

In a dropdown list, I would like to format text from my list ?

In my example below for instance, I'd like to improve the presentation of
"Variable 1 is built with ... (long text)"
with bold, line breaks, bullets....

```js
function getOption() {
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
  let selectedOption = '';
  output = selectElement.value;
  switch (output) {
    case "var1":
      selectedOption = "Variable 1 is built with ... (long text)";
      break;
    case "var2":
      selectedOption = "Variable 2 is important because... (long text)";
      break;
    default:
      selectedOption = "default selected";
  }
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = selectedOption;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="var1">Variable 1</option>
    <option value="var2">Variable 2</option>
    <option value="var3">Variable 3</option>
  </select>
</p>

<button onclick="getOption()"> Check option </button>

<p> The value of the option selected is:
  <span class="output"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: why don't you use `.innerHTML` instead of `textContent` ?

Comment: Can't you use the span tag for that ?

Comment: I'm just new to this language. Can you show me an example with .innerHTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` and style string directly like:

```js
function getOption() {
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
  let selectedOption = '';
  output = selectElement.value;
  switch (output) {
    case "var1":
      selectedOption = "<br /><b>Variable 1</b> is built with<br />...<br />(long text)";
      break;
    case "var2":
      selectedOption = "<br /><b>Variable 2</b> is important because... (long text)";
      break;
    default:
      selectedOption = "<br /><b>default</b> selected";
  }
  document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = selectedOption;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="var1">Variable 1</option>
    <option value="var2">Variable 2</option>
    <option value="var3">Variable 3</option>
  </select>
</p>

<button onclick="getOption()"> Check option </button>

<p> The value of the option selected is:
  <span class="output"></span>
</p>
```

Reference:

- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)